# Making two string methods into one method

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to put two string methods together so that they can be used as a shorter method. Specifically I am trying to make a method that will both make a string lowercase and remove punctuation. Regularly you can just do:

```
import string
s.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)).lower()
```

but I want it to look like:

```
s.removeall()
```

I've tried defining a function but I'm not sure how I would go about actually putting it into one sense it doesn't connect to anything and python wouldn't read it as a method anyways.

I tried this:

```
import string
def removeall():
    translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)).lower()

s.removeall()
```

Comment: Generally, you cannot add methods to built-in types (without some dark magic).

Comment: just use removall(s) and define accordingly. Unless you want to make a class which is string, has all string methods, then add your method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't be able to make a method of `str` easily, but there's nothing stopping you from writing a standalone utility function:

```
def removeall(s):
    return s.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)).lower()
```

You would use it as `s = removeall(s)`. Keep in mind that strings are immutable objects. There is no such thing as an in-place operation on a string. Your original expression `s.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)).lower()` creates a new string, and therefore has no net effect if you don't save the result. The same applies for the function from.